# Algorithm for discrete volume intersection

Tags: algorithm, volume, intersection, discrete-mathematics

I'm searching for an algorithm (or a python library) which can give the size of the intersection of multiple 3D volumes.

However, the volumes are not known by their equations, I just have a list of points in their boundaries.

In fact for each volume I know a list of couple (x,r) where r is a relation between y and z like a.y +b.z = c. Such as for each (y,z) respecting the relation r, (x,y,z) is in the boundary of the volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only points, you need then to build first the volume and then do the intersection.
I would suggest that you look at the VTK library, it can handle meshes and has many other
nice functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I succeed to create the meshes of my volumes, however, I'm still stuck for this intersection part. I wanted to use the vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter class, which seems to be exactly what I need, but I'm coding in python, and there is no binding for this class. Do you know any other function available on python which could help me?

Comment: Since VTK 6.2, class vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter has been wrapped for Python.